# javascript; Having trouble getting images to not replace eachother

Tags: javascript

So I have a 3x3 board that has 9 images, all initialized to an image named blank.
I have an x & o image that I am trying to place without placing it in a spot already occupied by anything besides "blank". Here is the code I have for the o image, a random number is assigned and I add some conditions but it's not working, it still replaces image x and image o with image o. Is there something wrong with my conditions or should I an if/else or am I missing something? I appreciate any help, thank you.

ok so I updated the code but now the x image isn't showing up at all. the form name is pokemon, do i need to add .image to get it to work?

```
 var x = "pikachu.jpg";
 var o = "Meowth.jpg";
 var blank = "ball.jpg";             

 function b1Move(imageName){
 temp2=imageName;
 if(document.pokemon[temp2].src==blank)  
 document.pokemon[temp2].src=x;
 cMove();
 }
```

and the html for the images looks like this:

```
 <a href="javascript:b1Move('b1')"><img src="ball.jpg" height=150 width=150 name=b1         
 id =b1  > </a>
```

Comment: what are the variables X and o... src is going to give you the complete address including the http:// part.. is the x and o variables the complete url?

Comment: could you keep track of where the images are in an array, and then just check that for a value (say blank is 0, anything not blank is 1)?

Comment: var x="x.jpg"; var o="o.jpg";

Answer (score 0):

You're using `=` instead of `==` in your conditionals. You can fix it like this:

```
if(document.pokemon.b8.src==blank)
```

`document.pokemon.b8.src==blank` is an *assignment* and will always return true (assuming you assign an actual path and not the empty string), whereas `document.pokemon.b8.src==blank` is an *equality comparison* and will only return true if the left and right arguments are equal.

On another note, you shouldn't need 9 different `b#Move` functions. You should be able to parameterize the square:

```
function bNMove(bn){
  if(document.pokemon[bn].src==blank)
    document.pokemon[bn].src=x;
  cMove();
}
```

And you'd call it like this: `bNMove('b9')`